# Why doesn't Scala's BigDecimal have a ZERO?

Tags: scala, bigdecimal, zero

It's easy enough to create:

```
object zero extends BigDecimal(java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

I'm just wondering whether this was an oversight, or if there was a conscious decision to not add this and, if so, are there reasons why I should avoid the code above. Perhaps having to do with the `MathContext`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd think it's because usually you don't need it. Whereas in Java you need to type something like

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(1.23).add(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

in Scala, there are number conversions that mean you can write

```
val b = BigDecimal(1.23) + 0
```

You can also write it simply as `BigDecimal(0)`. If you're instantiating that a lot you might want to cache it as a named value (as for any other number), but you won't normally need to, and I think it helps simplify the API if you remove special cases that you have to remember.

Answer (score 17):

If I had to guess, it's because the expected way to get that value would be like this:

```
val zero: BigDecimal = 0
```

Comment: Good point. Thanks for your answer but I'm accepting Luigi's answer because I think it's more detailed and so more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrection of an old thread for the sake of completeness. Scala actually has something similar to java `BigDecimal.ZERO`, you can access it with [`BigDecimalIsFractional.zero`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric$$BigDecimalIsFractional.html#zero:T).

As previous answers already pointed out most of the time the *literal* `0` will be fine. Having said that, Context Bounds can be useful with generic code:

```
def zero[T: Numeric](): Unit = {
  val evidence = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  val zero = evidence.zero
  println(s"${zero} is a ${zero.getClass.getSimpleName} defined at ${evidence.getClass.getName}")
}

zero[BigDecimal]() // 0 is a BigDecimal defined in scala.math.Numeric$BigDecimalIsFractional$
zero[Double]() // 0.0 is a Double defined in scala.math.Numeric$DoubleIsFractional$
zero[Int]() // 0 is a Integer defined at scala.math.Numeric$IntIsIntegral$
```